# LINQ-To-SQL row number greater than

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

If i have an object of type Photo and a Result set which is sorted in a particular order, is there a way for me to get the position of the current Photo object in the result set. and then get all objects that would follow it?

Comment: Also how would you get the object that would precede it? I'm trying to do this without having to get the whole collection from SQL

Comment: Do you you have a result set in memory that has all the Photos, or do you want to go back to the database to get the single next / previous Photo?

Comment: I was kind of hoping there would be a Row_Number like entity which i could go greater than this objects position without having it in memory

Comment: No, a database could regroup the items, especially if there is a clustered index involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sorting against an Id:

```
// gets the previous photo, or null if none:
var previousPhoto = db.Photos
    .Where(p => p.Id < currentPhotoId)
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.Id)
    .FirstOrDefault();

// gets the next photo, or null if none:
var nextPhoto = db.Photos
    .Where(p => p.Id > currentPhotoId)
    .OrderBy(p => p.Id)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

If you have custom ordering, you'd need to replace the `OrderBy/OrderByDescending` expression with your custom ordering. You'd also need to use the same ordering criteria in `Where()` to get only those photos before or after the current photo.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this (not terribly efficient):

```
var result =
  photos.Select((p, i) => new { Index = i, Photo = p })
  .SkipWhile(x => x.Photo != photo).Skip(1);
```

This will give you all photos following `photo` combined with their index in the original collection.

Comment: SkipWhile includes an indexed overload.

Comment: Yes, but that overload is only useful if you want to use the index to determine what to skip. I want to keep the original index across both the `SkipWhile` and the `Skip`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand correctly but this might help:

```
var result = photos.Skip(100); // 100 would be the position of current object.

// if you don't know the index of the current object:
// This won't work on LINQ to SQL directly, do it on a list or something.
var result = photos.SkipWhile(x => x != currentObject).Skip(1);
```

In reality, if you are dealing with a database, there should be some identifier (a set of columns) you are sorting by. If you want to do the whole thing on the server side, you can grab the properties of the current object and filter the result set specifically for objects that would come after that in the sort order you want.

Comment: How do i get the position of the current object though.

Answer (score 0):

Index of the photo:

```
result.IndexOf(photo);
```

Items after it:

```
result.SkipWhile((q, i) => i <= result.IndexOf(photo));
```

Comment: I'm assuming that result is already sorted by him, and not the order coming from the database.